# Error deserializing JSON data to Dictionary <string, string>

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

Here is the JSON that I want to deserialize into Dictionary using native Javascript support.

```
string data = "{"Symptom":[true,true,true],"Action":[true,true],"AllArea":true}";
```

But when I attempt to deserialize using below code

Dictionary values = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize>(data);

It gives me an error stating
`"Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array"`

I am using .Net Framework 3.5. Please help me getting this done.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you can not convert that to a dictionary directly... i think `deserializer` needs a corresponding type, with intelligible property names with type,

i think you can convert to a `type`, then generate your `dictionary`, something like:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public List<bool> Symptom { get; set; }
        public List<bool> Action { get; set; }
        public bool AllArea { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string, List<bool>> getDic()
        {
            // this is for example, and many many different may be implement
            // maybe some `reflection` for add property dynamically or ...

            var oDic = new Dictionary<string, List<bool>>();
            oDic.Add("Symptom", this.Symptom);
            oDic.Add("Action", this.Action);
            oDic.Add("AllArea", new List<bool>() { AllArea });
            return oDic;
        }
    }
```

then:

```
string data = "{\"Symptom\":[true,true,true],\"Action\":[true,true],\"AllArea\":true}";
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer aa = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var o = aa.Deserialize<MyClass>(data);
var dic = o.getDic();
```

anyhow, it was a good question